# Clicking on "Save Tag Edits" displays JSON response

Tags: bug, tags, edits

Starting today, if I click on "edit tags", then on <kbd>Save Tag Edits</kbd>, the browser displays a JSON response rather than displaying the question.

Reproduced on Safari 12 and Firefox 63.

(A side complaint: I used to be able to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the tag-editing field to save tag edits, but that hasn't worked for months.)

[image: Screen capture]